# "The Prefix of Output File Names" or "The Prefix of Output Files Name" or both are wrong?

Tags: programming

I point this out for making it clear what I try to achieve.

I'm writing a little documentation for my command line utility.
It generates two files:

- `{Prefix}-{4096}bits.public`
- `{Prefix}-{4096}bits.private`

that contain Prefix value within their names.

How could I formulate the essence of feature (-o, --output) that modifies the Prefix within file name simultaneously for both files?

-o, --output is **"The Prefix of Output File Names"**

-o, --output is **"The Prefix of Output Files Name"**

-o, --output is **"The Prefix of Output Files' Names"** *(I guess this is the correct one)*

-o, --output is **"The Name Prefix of Output Files"**

Are there any other options? What is the appropriate one?

Comment: In computer contexts, we usually write *filename* as one word. Then this problem doesn't come up.

Comment: @Barmar is on the money here. I reckon this is an example of an xy problem- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: If you do want to use them as separate words, I would say *the prefix of names of output files*

Comment: @Barmar I suggest you combine these comments into an answer as this is correct

Comment: -o, --output  “The prefix to use in output filenames”   But why is this not --prefix ??

Comment: I really can't understand the close votes here.

Comment: @Jim This is a really excellent remark. I was reusing the CLI lib code, so I kept the naming untouched. You're certainly right, I have to rename the option --output to --prefix.

Comment: Stop closing answers as off topic you power abusers; who are you to say what's helpful to the world. Let knowledge live and butt out! You are a disgrace for closing questions and should be ashamed of yourselves.

Comment: You missed the extra "The". `The prefix of the output filename.` "The" is key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to write this as a non-jargony English phrase, I would suggest:

> The prefix of names of output files

Hoever, the phrase "file name" has generally been combined into the compound word "filename" when referring to computer files, you can find it in online dictionaries:

- [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/filename)
- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/filename?s=t)

So you should just say

> The prefix of output filenames

or

> The output filename prefix

Comment: `The prefix of the output filename`. "The" is key.

Comment: Are you talking about the first or second "the"? The second one is optional when "filenames" is plural.

Comment: It's a simple matter of reading it out loud and picking the one that sounds the best. Dropping the second "the" does not sound as good as keeping it in. "The prefix of the output filename." that is how any sensible person would talk in real life.

Comment: @KyleBridenstine But "The prefix of output filenames" sounds fine to me, too. Like I said, it's optional when "filenames" is plural.